# Persistent JSON content

Tags: java, android, json

My problem is with saving content parsed from JSON file.
I want to save content, so after clearing app from recents JSON's content will remain undeleted. Actually JSON is being parsed, but after completely closing an app I must have network connection enabled to retrieve again JSON's content.
If more code is needed, I will add it - just say to do so.
Cheers!

```
package pl.bugbreaker.cherry56su.Docs;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import pl.bugbreaker.cherry56su.Docs.Download_data.download_complete;
import pl.bugbreaker.cherry56su.R;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import static android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.View;

public class DocsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements download_complete {

public ListView docs_list;
public ArrayList<Doc> documents = new ArrayList<Doc>();
public ListAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_docs);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Dokumenty");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    docs_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.docs_list);
    adapter = new ListAdapter(this);
    docs_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    Download_data download_data = new Download_data((download_complete) this);
    download_data.download_data_from_link("http://link.com/file.json");

}

public void get_data(String data)
{
    try {
        JSONArray data_array=new JSONArray(data);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < data_array.length() ; i++)
        {
            JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(data_array.get(i).toString());
            Doc add=new Doc();
            add.doc = obj.getString("doc");
            add.doc_link = obj.getString("doc_link");
            documents.add(add);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}

}
```

---

**EDIT:**
I will check all of these answers soon, when I finish, answer will be checked and problem solved at all.

Comment: store `obj.toString()` into preference and use it later

Comment: Huh, but how? Make something like new activity specified for storing? Oh, and it's `obj.getString()`, not `.toString()`. Should I make `toString()`, and then store it?

Comment: nopes , once you get your data then store it into `preference` and inside `onCreate` fetch it and if retrieved string is non-empty then use it to display your data

Comment: But how to store it inside a `Preference`? Just give me any link relating to storing.

Comment: just google `store string in preference android`

Comment: Oh, you mean **this**. I've just understood how to do it, thanks!

Comment: Here is the link for storing in shared preferences: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html and here is a link for your storage options in Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Persistent JSON content

You can use gson to parse JSON data more easily.
In your build.gradle file add this dependency.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

Then create a POJO class to parse JSON data.

**Example POJO class:**

```
  public class AppGeneralSettings {
    @SerializedName("key1")
String data;


    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

}
```

sample JSON object

```
{
   "key1":"hellow world!"
}
```

- To parse a json string from internet use this snippet

  ```
  AppGeneralSettings data=new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, AppGeneralSettings.class);
  ```

Then add a helper class to store and retrieve JSON data to and from preferences.

**Example: Helper class to store data**

```
public class AppPreference {
    private static final String FILE_NAME = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".apppreference";
    private static final String APP_GENERAL_SETTINGS = "app_general_settings";
    private final SharedPreferences preferences;

    public AppPreference(Context context) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public SharedPreferences.Editor setGeneralSettings(AppGeneralSettings appGeneralSettings) {
        return preferences.edit().putString(APP_GENERAL_SETTINGS, new Gson().toJson(appGeneralSettings));
    }

    public AppGeneralSettings getGeneralSettings() {
        return new Gson().fromJson(preferences.getString(APP_GENERAL_SETTINGS, "{}"), AppGeneralSettings.class);
    }
}
```

**To save data**

```
new AppPreference().setGeneralSettings(appGeneralSettings).commit();
```

**To retrieve data**

```
 AppGeneralSettings appGeneralSettings = new AppPreference().getGeneralSettings();
```

Comment: Could you tell me, what is exactly "key1"? Is that just something like `android:key="key1"` in preference file?

Comment: it is just a custom name used in the json string